# Sort based on array length within array of objects in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, sorting

Consider the following example,

```
var arrayOfObject = [
{name: 'ron', data: [1,3,5]},
{name: 'raj', data: [2,3]},
{name: 'roy', data: [1]}
]
```

In the view, I need to sort the objects in ascending order based on the length of `data` array in each objects.

In the above example roy, raj, ron.

I could always loop through the array, find the length and sort it, But was wondering if there was a way to sort it using **Angular's OrderBy Filter** (view or controller).

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your can use angular's [OrderBy filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

In view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfObject | orderBy:'data.length'">
```

Or in controller:

```
var ordered = $filter("orderBy")(arrayOfObject, "data.length");
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpeo518n/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfObject | orderBy:'data.length'">
    {{item.name}}:{{item.data.length}}
  </div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.arrayOfObject = [{
      name: 'ron',
      data: [1, 3, 5]
    },
    {
      name: 'raj',
      data: [2, 3]
    },
    {
      name: 'roy',
      data: [1]
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
ASEC:
  <div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfObject | orderBy:'data.length'">
    {{item.name}}:{{item.data.length}}
  </div>
<br/>
DESC:
  <div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfObject | orderBy:-'data.length'">
    {{item.name}}:{{item.data.length}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array| orderBy:'data.length'>
```

here `orderBy` takes property of `data`

Answer (score 2):

We can use orderby clause

For Ascending

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfObject | orderBy:'data.length'">
    {{item.name}}:{{item.data.length}}
  </div>
```

For Descending order we need to use '-' sign (inside single quotes)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfObject | orderBy:'-data.length'">
    {{item.name}}:{{item.data.length}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){

var arrayOfObject = [
  {name: 'ron', data: [1,3,5]},
  {name: 'raj', data: [2,3]},
  {name: 'roy', data: [1]}
]
$scope.arrayOfObject = $filter("orderBy")(arrayOfObject, 'data.length');
  console.log($scope.arrayOfObject);
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
</div>
```